# Why the extension with specific key declared can access chrome:// pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

As we know, by default chrome extensions doesn't have access to `chrome://` pages such as `chrome://extensions` and `chrome://settings`. ( Of course we can change `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` flags however **the following question is based on that we didn't change the default flags**).

Recently I happen to find [ChromeVox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en) (offered by chrome.google.com) can work well in all pages including `chrome://` pages. I checked the source code for this extension and find as long as we add the following line in `manifest.json` for **any extension**, the extension can work well in `chrome://` pages.

```
"key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEGBi/oD7Yl/Y16w3+gee/95/EUpRZ2U6c+8orV5ei+3CRsBsoXI/DPGBauZ3rWQ47aQnfoG00sXigFdJA2NhNK9OgmRA2evnsRRbjYm2BG1twpaLsgQPPus3PyczbDCvhFu8k24wzFyEtxLrfxAGBseBPb9QrCz7B4k2QgxD/CwIDAQAB"
```

So it looks like chrome has something like whitelist to allow specific extensions to break the default restrictions. Am I right? Is there official guide to clarify this behavior?

### Appendix:

The following is a sample extension, you will find with the `key`, console will output `test` even in `chrome://extensions` pages; however once removing the `key`, nothing happens.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEGBi/oD7Yl/Y16w3+gee/95/EUpRZ2U6c+8orV5ei+3CRsBsoXI/DPGBauZ3rWQ47aQnfoG00sXigFdJA2NhNK9OgmRA2evnsRRbjYm2BG1twpaLsgQPPus3PyczbDCvhFu8k24wzFyEtxLrfxAGBseBPb9QrCz7B4k2QgxD/CwIDAQAB"
}
```

content.js:

```
console.log('test');
```

Comment: You can use whitelisted features in locally loaded extensions, but you cannot publish them to the webstore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `"key"` property in manifest.json uniquely [defines the extension's ID](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key) in encrypted form.
2. Some Google extensions are unfairly(?) [whitelisted](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/api/_manifest_features.json) by ID in the source code of chromium.
   In this case, [ChromeVox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/chrome_extensions_client.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1472469725&l=130):

   ```cpp
   scripting_whitelist_.push_back(extension_misc::kChromeVoxExtensionId);
   ```

   And then this whitelist is checked to see whether an extension can run *everywhere* in [PermissionsData::CanExecuteScriptEverywhere](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/permissions/permissions_data.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=68), which is accessed in [CheckRestrictedUrls](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/permissions/permissions_data_unittest.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=C&rcl=1472469725&l=79) where we can see restricted schemes: `chrome://`, `chrome-extension://`, `chrome-debugger://`

Comment: Technically speaking, the key is simply the base64-encoded public key of the keypair used to sign CRX, and the ID is a truncated SHA256 hash of said key.